# Regular expression to get the last parts segments of a URL

Tags: java, regex

How can I get the last two parts of a URL. For example if a URL is

```
http://stackoverflow/java/regex
```

I would like to get the following

```
 java/regex
```

The regex ".*/(.*)" will give me the last segment but I struggling to get the last two parts.

Comment: What do you except as a result if http://stackoverflow/java/regex/part3 ?

Comment: @Toilal OP said `last two parts of a URL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
String url = "http://stackoverflow/java/regex";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".+/(.+/.+)$");
Pattern otherPattern = Pattern.compile(".+/(.+)/.+$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
matcher = otherPattern.matcher(url);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
java/regex
java
```

Comment: @user86834 although fge is actually right. Dividing paths of URLs programmatically is better done by creating URI objects.

Comment: Can i modify that regex only get the second from last segment in the URL?

Answer (score 7):

Do NOT use regexes for this when Java has [`URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html)!

```
final URI uri = URI.create("http://stackoverflow/java/regex");
uri.getPath().subString(1); // returns "java/regex"
```

Comment: I should have been clearer, I want to use this regext with ElasticSearch's pattern tokenizer so it indexes the last part of the url as a token. So I don't have access to the URI implementation in Java.

Comment: Indeed, you should have mentioned that ;) In this case I'd have suggested using `[^/]+/[^/]+$`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `java.net.URL`'s `getPath()` method

```
URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow/java/regex");
System.out.println(url.getPath());
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple!

It you have absolute urls:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("http://(^[/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+);
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourURL);
if (m.find()) {
    path1 = m.group(2);
    path2 = m.group(3);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would use the existing [URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class and the [getPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getPath%28%29) method to get the section following the host/port/protocol.

I'd certainly start with an existing class designed to break apart URL components and then work from there. If you use a regexp you're likely to run into and have to cater for lots of edge cases that the `URL` class already handles.

Answer (score 0):

Why not casting your URL to URI and call method getPath() ?